# Removing characters outside of brackets

Tags: html

I'm new to html, and I need a quick and simple way to delete data outside of brackets, for example "abc [123] abc 115", which I would like to return: 123

I would like it to work with lists,

```
abc [123] abc 115
abc [1253] abc 112
cac [123] abc 115
```

This would return

```
123
1253
123
```

Here is my code so far, I am stuck from here on

```
<textarea rows="40" cols="50"></textarea>
<button type="button">Generate</button>
```

Comment: html is mostly used for visuals. Regarding functions of websites have a look at PHP, javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use just pure HTML, some JavaScript or PHP will have to be used. If all content will keep with the same format that is provided, this simple function will work.

```js
function findNums() {
  var value = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
  value = value.split("[");
  value = value[1].split("]");
  alert(value[0]);
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="40" cols="50"></textarea>
<button type="button" onClick="findNums()">Generate</button>
```

Comment: thank you! so if i use <script src=a.js"></script> to use it on the page it should work?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a programming language. You cannot do that with HTML. Depending on where you get/process the data, you need to use JavaScript on the *client* side, or a *server* side language (Python, PHP, JavaScript, Java, ...).